# Render HTML element only if a regex matches in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to parse an XML Document and render a table based on a certain string. If there is a specific code I don't want that table to be rendered. Here is the simplified code I'm currently using without regex:

```
<xsl:template match="assortment">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="tgtable tgAssortment">
                <xsl:call-template name="countryCodes">
                    <xsl:with-param name="parStr" select="./countryCodes"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="parPos" select="1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td><div class="tgData"><xsl:value-of select="./totalPackRatio"/></div></td>
        <td><div class="tgData"><xsl:value-of select="./name"/></div></td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./styles/style"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The element `./countryCodes` is a string like this:

```
CB1-AT,CB1-CH,CB1-DE,CB2-FR,CB3-EE,CB3-LT,CB3-LV,CB3-SE,CB4-CZ
```

Or like this:

```
CB8-OSDE,CB8-OSBE,CB8-OSNL,CB8-OSCZ,CB8-OSGB,CB8-OSFR,CB8-OSPL,CB8-OSSK
```

In the second example all country codes start wit `CB8` in that case I don't want to render the complete `<tr>`. I wanted to check it with a simple regex like this: `(CB(?!8)\d)` and tried to implement it wit xsl:analyze. Here is my code:

```
<xsl:template match="assortment">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="./countryCodes" regex="CB(?!8)\d">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table class="tgtable tgAssortment">
                        <xsl:call-template name="countryCodes">
                            <xsl:with-param name="parStr" select="./countryCodes"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="parPos" select="1"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td><div class="tgData"><xsl:value-of select="./totalPackRatio"/></div></td>
                <td><div class="tgData"><xsl:value-of select="./name"/></div></td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./styles/style"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

This always gives me a stylesheet compilation error. I tried different regex and also using `xsl:value-of` as I thought it might be mandatory but this didn't work.

For debugging purposes I tried the following:

```
<xsl:template match="assortment">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="./countryCodes" regex="CB(?!8)\d">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <div><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></div>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="tgtable tgAssortment">
                <xsl:call-template name="countryCodes">
                    <xsl:with-param name="parStr" select="./countryCodes"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="parPos" select="1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td><div class="tgData"><xsl:value-of select="./totalPackRatio"/></div></td>
        <td><div class="tgData"><xsl:value-of select="./name"/></div></td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./styles/style"/>
</xsl:template>
```

this was compiled successfully but obviously doesn't give the results I want. But I think it shows there is some problem with rendering the table inside the `xsl:analyze-string'. I'm stuck with this. Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `countryCodes` always a comma-delimited list of code? Perhaps using `<xsl:template match="assortment[not(every $token in tokenize(countryCodes, ',') satisfies starts-with($token, 'CB8'))]">` suffices to write a match only for the elements where you don't have only codes starting with CB8.

Comment: What is `?!8` supposed to do, a negative lookahead? I don't think the regular expression syntax in XSLT/XPath 2 and later supports that unless you use processor specific flags to switch to the underlying platform's regular expression support like Java ones or .NET ones.

Comment: So for instance for Saxon .NET you could use `countryCodes[every $token in tokenize(., ',') satisfies matches($token, 'CB(?!8)\d', ';n')]`, the `;n` flag switches to the .NET regular expression syntax which supports a negative lookahead.

Comment: @MartinHonnen This absolutely did it! Thank you so much! If you write it as an answer I'll accept it. perhaps it helps someone else later

Comment: Your first suggested solution is what worked for me. I had the same problem with way simpler regexes without negative lookaheads. But I guess it is as you said, I'm using saxon .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to match on `assortment` elements where the `countryCodes` element has a comma delimited list of at least one code not starting with CB8 then using

```
<xsl:template match="assortment[not(every $token in tokenize(countryCodes, ',') satisfies starts-with($token, 'CB8'))]">
```

would do that.

As for a negative lookahead in regular expressions, that is not supported in the regular expression language XSLT and XPath 2.0 and later support, unless you use a processor dependent way to switch to the underlying platform's regular expression support e.g. for Saxon .NET use the flag `;n` to swith to .NET's language, there you could have e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="assortment[every $token in tokenize(countryCodes, ',') satisfies matches($token, '^CB(?!8)\d', ';n')]">
```

I think but I am not quite sure which Saxon versions and editions support that.